# How to write multiple outer left join in linq?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to outer join multiple tables. Here I have pasted my code what I am trying to do.

```
from o in entities.O
                             join p in entities.P on o.PID equals p.ID
                             join dC in entities.C on o.DCID equals dC.ID
                             join hC in entities.C on o.HCID equals hC.ID
                             join e in entities.E on pat.AN equals e.UID
                             join oT in entities.OT on o.OT equals oT.ID
                             join plt in entities.PLT on p.LT equals plt.ID
                             join puO in entities.PUO on o.PUTId equals puO.ID into pots
                             from x in pots.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join op in entities.OP on o.OPID equals op.ID
                             join prt in entities.PatientRelationshipTypes on pat.PRTId equals prt.ID
                             join secPRT in entities.PRT on pat.SRTId equals secPRT.ID
                             join patDiagCode in entities.PDiagnosisCodes on pat.ID equals patDiagCode.PID
                             //from y in pdc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join diagCode in entities.DCodes on patDiagCode.CodeID equals diagCode.ID into dc
                             from z in dc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             where o.ID == orderId
                             //from x in pots.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             //from y in pdc.DefaultIfEmpty()
...
...
```

How do I write correct syntax for multiple outer join in Linq?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the link. I tried that one but what I am trying to do is joining more than one tables.

Comment: The syntax is the same for one or more tables.

Comment: I tried but it gives me following error msg. `The name 'patDiagCode' is not in scope on the left side of 'equals'.  Consider swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'.`

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I finally figured it out.